# Conditionally generate word explanations in appendix

Tags: conditionals, appendices, keywords

Is there a way to declare a set of conceptual keywords with their explanation that will be taken and compiled into the appendix when one of the keywords is used throughout the documents body?

For example, when having a text containing a `keyword`, the appendix should contain a section with the explanation of `keyword`:

```
I use the \AddExplanationToAppendixFor{keyword} in the text.
```

Appendix:

```
keyword: A very special word I would like to elaborate on: bla blah
```

It would be awesome if the resulting PDF would contain a hyperref to the respective appendix's section:

```
I use the keyword¹ in the text.
```

How could this be realized?

Comment: Did you already have a look at packages like ``glossaries``? This should do exactly what you, if I get you right.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34641/which-tool-to-use-an-index-or-a-glossary

Comment: `glossaries`. Of course! Thank you @BenediktBauer. I wonder what I did wrong querying google to not find `glossaries` would fits my needs.

Yet a susequent question on glossaries: Is it possible to add paragraphs to the description? I'd like to have a certain pattern for my explanations, like name, meaning and additional information.

Comment: From the ``glossaries`` user manual: "If you want a paragraph break in the description use ``\glspar``. However note that not all glossary styles support multiline descriptions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put together the answer to your question and the multi-line thing from the comments, consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

% Define some glossary entry
\newglossaryentry{test}{name=Test, description={A multiline description.\glspar This one has two lines}}

\begin{document}
\gls{test}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

You have to call `latex`, `makeglossaries`, `latex` to get it all done.

According to the glossaries user manual the `makeglossaries` thing works only with an installed `perl` on your system. If don't have perl, you must call `makeindex` or `xindy` "by hand" -- in this case you must give some additional parameters that the `makeglossaries` tool collects by itself.